# Combine Querys and Increase SQL Performance

Tags: php, sql, mysql, performance, yii2

I have a MySQL performance problem. This is my base query:

```
            $serviceMaterialsQuery = ServiceMaterial::find()
            ->joinWith(['serviceOperation', 'serviceArticle', 'pattern', 'serviceOperation.product', 'serviceOperation.order', 'invoice'])
            ->orderBy([
                "service_operation.typ" => SORT_DESC,
                "service_operation.charge_number" => SORT_DESC,
                "service_operation.year" => SORT_DESC,
                "service_material.service_article_id" => SORT_DESC,
            ])
            ->andWhere(['service_operation.order_id' => 3998])
            ->andWhere('service_operation_patterns.id = 54 OR (service_operation_patterns.active = 1 AND service_operation_patterns.is_inspection = 1)');

        $serviceMaterials = $serviceMaterialsQuery->all();
```

I iterate through each row from the result of this query and execute two additional queries to retrieve two columns:

```
        $lastChangedQuery = ServiceMaterial::find()->andWhere([
            'service_operation.charge_number' => $serviceMaterial->serviceOperation->charge_number,
            'service_operation.typ' => $serviceMaterial->serviceOperation->typ,
            'service_operation.year' => $serviceMaterial->serviceOperation->year,
            'service_material.service_article_id' => $serviceMaterial->service_article_id,
            'service_material.install_location' => $serviceMaterial->install_location,
        ])->joinWith('serviceOperation');
        $lastChangedQuery->andWhere('service_material.exchange IS NOT NULL');
        $lastChangedQuery->andWhere(['!=', 'service_operation.id', $serviceMaterial->service_operation_id]);
        $lastChangedQuery->orderBy(['service_material.exchange' => SORT_DESC]);

        $lastChanged = $lastChangedQuery->one();


        $lastChangedGroupedArticleQuery = ServiceMaterial::find()->andWhere([
            'service_operation.charge_number' => $serviceMaterial->serviceOperation->charge_number,
            'service_operation.typ' => $serviceMaterial->serviceOperation->typ,
            'service_operation.year' => $serviceMaterial->serviceOperation->year,
            'service_article.group' => $serviceMaterial->serviceArticle->group,
            'service_material.install_location' => $serviceMaterial->install_location,
        ])
            ->andWhere(['!=', 'service_operation.id', $serviceMaterial->service_operation_id])
            ->andWhere(['!=', 'service_material.service_article_id', $serviceMaterial->service_article_id])
            ->andWhere('service_material.exchange IS NOT NULL')
            ->orderBy(['service_material.exchange' => SORT_DESC])
            ->joinWith(['serviceOperation', 'serviceArticle']);

         $lastChangedGroupArticle = $lastChangedGroupedArticleQuery->one();
```

I only need the column "exchange" from the 2 queries that I am executing per row from the first query.

So my question is: how can I combine these 3 queries? So I have my base query with ActiveRecord and 2 extra columns like "lastExchanged" and "lastExchangedGroup."

My problem is these columns and the two queries are in relation with the first one and more than one table.

Pure SQL:

First

```
SELECT `service_material`.* 
FROM `service_material` 
LEFT JOIN `service_operation` ON `service_material`.`service_operation_id` = `service_operation`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `service_article` ON `service_material`.`service_article_id` = `service_article`.`number` 
LEFT JOIN `service_operation_patterns` ON `service_operation`.`pattern_id` = `service_operation_patterns`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `products` ON `service_operation`.`typ` = `products`.`typ` 
     AND `service_operation`.`year` = `products`.`year` 
     AND `service_operation`.`charge_number` = `products`.`charge_number` 
     AND `service_operation`.`producttypeid` = `products`.`producttype_id` 
LEFT JOIN `order` ON `service_operation`.`order_id` = `order`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `invoice` ON `service_material`.`id` = `invoice`.`service_material_id` 
WHERE (`service_operation`.`order_id`=3998) 
AND (service_operation_patterns.id = 54 OR
     (service_operation_patterns.active = 1 AND service_operation_patterns.is_inspection = 1)
    ) 
AND (`destroyed` IS NULL) 
ORDER BY `service_operation`.`typ` DESC,
         `service_operation`.`charge_number` DESC, 
         `service_operation`.`year` DESC, 
         `service_material`.`service_article_id` DESC
```

Second:

```
SELECT `service_material`.* 
FROM `service_material` 
LEFT JOIN `service_operation` ON `service_material`.`service_operation_id` = `service_operation`.`id`
WHERE ((`service_operation`.`charge_number`='008040') AND
       (`service_operation`.`typ`='03') AND 
       (`service_operation`.`year`='2022') AND 
       (`service_material`.`service_article_id`='998650000000') AND 
       (`service_material`.`install_location`=0)
      ) AND 
      (service_material.exchange IS NOT NULL) AND 
      (`service_operation`.`id` != 158912) 
ORDER BY `service_material`.`exchange` DESC
```

Third:

```
SELECT `service_material`.* 
FROM `service_material` 
LEFT JOIN `service_operation` ON `service_material`.`service_operation_id` = `service_operation`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `service_article` ON `service_material`.`service_article_id` = `service_article`.`number` 
WHERE ((`service_operation`.`charge_number`='008040') AND
       (`service_operation`.`typ`='03') AND 
       (`service_operation`.`year`='2022') AND  
       (`service_article`.`group` IS NULL) AND 
       (`service_material`.`install_location`=0)
      ) AND (`service_operation`.`id` != 158912) AND
      (`service_material`.`service_article_id` != '998650000000') AND 
      (service_material.exchange IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER BY `service_material`.`exchange` DESC
```

Comment: What is the result of SELECT @@version; ?   From a MySQL Command Prompt?

Comment: best would be to get he generated queries and see if `explain select` gives some insights

Comment: That is why it is important to know what version of MySQL is running.

Comment: Analyze the explain to see what indexes are used and see if there are some missing (which is mostly the case).

Comment: version: 10.11.6-MariaDB-1:10.11.6+maria~ubu2004 but i think you dont understand my problem. The MySQL Server is fast. My Problem is my base Query is responding 200 rows for example and then i`ll foreach them and execute for every row these 2 other queries.

Comment: and the problem of it is that the sum of the queries are over 400 and that makes it slow. i am using only one column of both extra queries and want to querie them once in the base query so i only got one query.

Comment: For a very simple query, 90% is overhead.  Even more overhead if the client and server are geographically separated.  Please provide the generated SQL.